# How to mute all sound in a page with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio, mute

How can I mute all sound on my page with JS?

This should mute HTML5 `<audio>` and `<video>` tags along with Flash and friends.

Comment: We need more info. Can you elaborate? Is this in a plugin/users fit?

Comment: @mplungjan, I have an audio icon on my page which will toggle sound on/off when clicked on.

Comment: Sound playing in Flash is completely separate from sound playing in HTML/JavaScript. Look at the API's you used to play the sounds, they usually have methods to stop the sound and adjust the volume.

Comment: @Shmiddty tell that to youtube!

Comment: @Ramin I highly doubt you are working on Youtube.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rule #1: Never enable audio autoplay upon page loading.

Anyway I'll show for HTML5 using jQuery:

```
// WARNING: Untested code ;)

window.my_mute = false;

$('#my_mute_button').bind('click', function(){

    $('audio,video').each(function(){

        if (!my_mute ) {

            if( !$(this).paused ) {
                $(this).data('muted',true); //Store elements muted by the button.
                $(this).pause(); // or .muted=true to keep playing muted
            }

        } else {

            if( $(this).data('muted') ) {
                $(this).data('muted',false);
                $(this).play(); // or .muted=false
            }

        }
    });

    my_mute = !my_mute;

});
```

Flash Media Players depends on the custom API (hopefuly) exposed to JavaScript.

But you get the idea, iterate through media, check/store playing status, and mute/unmute.

Comment: isn't there something audio api that we could use...like reroute destination to new node and don't connect it to speaker?

Comment: Only seen this when generating procedural audio with [WebAudio API](http://modernweb.com/2014/03/31/creating-sound-with-the-web-audio-api-and-oscillators/)

Comment: Rule #0 never declare global variables

Comment: Of course, ten years later it's better to store it in your Redux status than using a global variable. 

Answer (score 31):

This can be done in vanilla JS:

```
// Mute a singular HTML5 element
function muteMe(elem) {
    elem.muted = true;
    elem.pause();
}

// Try to mute all video and audio elements on the page
function mutePage() {
    document.querySelectorAll("video, audio").forEach((elem) => muteMe(elem));
}
```

This, of course, only works with `<video>` or `<audio>` elements, as items like Flash or JS initialized audio are impossible to restrict programmatically in general.

Comment: This also unfortunately doesn't work for those elements in iframes (which is very typical for advertisements..).

In general this, (and even less the other answers), are not a good solution.

Comment: @Christian it's the best solution that there is :) if the iframes are on the same domain then you can use this approach for it, though it's a little more involved

Answer (score 6):

I did it like this:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach(function(audio) {
    audio.muted = true;
});
```

Comment: instead of Array.prototype.slice.call you can use Array.from

Comment: replaced `Array.prototype.slice` with `[].slice` to make it more readable

Comment: I added an answer with what I meant too, I guess it's more ways to write it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66562772/3577695

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('audio, video')].forEach(el => el.muted = true)
```

or

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('audio, video')).forEach(el => el.muted = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

@zach-saucier

```
function muteMe(elem) {elem.muted = false;elem.pause();}// Try to mute all video and audio elements on the page
function mutePage() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("video, audio");

    [].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) { muteMe(elem); });
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hold a reference to all audio/video elements inside an array and then make a function which performs a loop over them while setting the `.muted=true`.

Comment: can you explain your solution a bit more please