# Disable sound in capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing, capybara-webkit

I'm running a website signup spec with

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

I noticed that when the test completes the signup, the "successful signup" sound (the one that can be heard when signing up from a "normal" browser) starts.

I think this is the normal behaviour, but my questions are:

- Is there a way to disable sounds in capybara-webkit?
- Is there a way to mute the browser instance?

Like when we want to not load images and we use `config.skip_image_loading`

Comment: If you know how the sound is created (e.g. an `<audio>` node) you may be able to mute it through Javascript (`execute_script`). See [disable-sound-in-browser-window-with-js-or-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084472/disable-sound-in-browser-window-with-js-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `capybara-webkit` doesn't expose this setting, as `Qt` (`capybara-webkit` depends on a WebKit implementation from `Qt`) doesn't expose it either.

Ref: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/555

But you probably can achieve it with other approaches like:

- Execute javascript to remove the audio tags or mute the player:

`page.execute_script("your_js_here")`

- Block the audio urls:

`config.block_url("example.com/path_to_audio_files/*")`