# Preventing sound from advertisements on certain websites

Tags: javascript, audio

I tried to use this code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044761/how-to-mute-all-sound-in-a-page-with-js) in StackExchange to prevent advertisements sound on certain websites.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach((audio)=>{
    audio.muted = true;
});
```

I implemented the code this way:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        addicto
// @namespace   nms
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  let sites = ['mako.co.il'];
  let href = window.location.href;
  for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    if (href.includes(sites[i])) {
      Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach((audio)=>{
        audio.muted = true;
      });
    }
  }

  // If href includes the value of the iteration on the "sites" array, do stuff.
});
```

This didn't work and I still hear sounds from the site ([mako.co.il](http://mako.co.il)). Maybe this is because the code doesn't work when the sound is coming from advertisement scripts?

If so, maybe a decent solution would be to disable any other script beside my scripts on the desired website? or maybe something else?

Comment: You DOM hasn’t loaded yet, when you run that script, most likely. Wrap that in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

Comment: @Xufox I just tried that. Sadly, didn't work... I've updated the question with the exact code.

Comment: In that case, those `<audio>` elements are inserted dynamically. Try a `MutationObserver`!

Comment: The meaning here is that I should "observe for DOM mutations involving addition of audio tags related to the video in the advertisement and response with removing them", right?

Comment: That’s pretty much it, yes.

Comment: `document.addEventListener`?  Keep in mind, ads especially are loaded later, often after the page content is loaded.  They can also be in iframes.

Comment: @Brad, is there a "general" way to listen to all audio tags in an efficient way? Something more efficient than a 10 milliseconds `setInterval`? (of course, I should learn of `mutationObserver`.

Comment: Why not make a browser extension and mute the tab?

Comment: Muting the tab manually each time is a pain, I'm sure you meant something else. What is it?